# How to deal with a hacked laptop that's being remotely monitored

Tags: malware, attacks

One of friends hacked my laptop and now whenever I come online he can tell what tabs are opened in my browser, so I think he is remotely monitoring me. I don't know how he did this, since I didn't take anything from him.

I use Ubuntu, the firewall is enabled, remote connections are switched off, so how can he see what I'm doing?  I can't even access my router on 192.168.1.1 any more.

Comment: Step 1: Remove and reinstall your operating system. Step 2: Get better friends.

Comment: Do you use FireFox?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7Qmg.jpg

Comment: i use chromium as well as firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably infected by a trojan. The first thing you should do is to change all your personal passwords (mail, facebook, gmail, etc) from another machine !

You can use the terminal to see what are the established connections :

*netstat -anp --tcp --udp | grep LISTEN*

See what are the processes loaded on boot and eliminate the useless ones.
You can use Wireshark to monitor the ingoing/outgoing traffic.

You can install Clamav :

*sudo apt-get install clamav*

and scan your hole system :

*clamscan -r --remove /*

Comment: You don't know how  a rootkit works do you?

Comment: A trojan works on the same manner, no? With a tool like Njrat you can install a server on the linux victim machine and have a remote control of the hole system. Am I wrong?

Comment: Nope you are completely right. Yet you don't seem to understand that you can't trust the system anymore, you can't recover it and you can't trust any commands you execute on it.

Comment: A rootkit modifies the operating system so that it hides its existence. So if the rootkit lived in a file named /tmp/rootkit, and you typed ls /tmp, you would not see the file. If you did a ps, you would not see a rootkit process. If you dumped memory, it would patch the addresses it lives at with some other bytes. "Trojan" is simply a way to get someone to install malware - a rootkit is a type of stealthy behavior.

Comment: So our friend should reinstall Ubuntu? :)

Comment: Correct! This is the only way to be sure

Comment: but what if after reinstallation he does the same to me again ?? how can i protect myself

Comment: @Raja Dey - after the re-installation, 1) make sure the first thing you do with your Ubuntu is to update and patch your system. 2) Do not open or use anything that this 'friend' has ever sent you. 3) Change your router's password, just in case. 4) Change all your passwords to services which you have logged using your home computer or home network. 5) Tell this person he is a worthless piece of <user-your-imagination> and don't ever trust him again.

Comment: how can i patch the system as you have mentioned @ Lex

Comment: @RajaDey: You can use the Software Manager, or open up a command prompt and type in these 2 commands: "sudo apt-get update" and "sudo apt-get full-upgrade".

Comment: after reinstallation, can i chat with him through facebook or he might hack me through facebook..... is thr any way to protect myself

Comment: You can chat with him in Facebook, but don't trust him anymore, don't open the links he send to you and don't accept files from him. Although, if you chat with him through Skype, be careful, because he could get your IP. As said above by @vibez_well, you could  threaten that you're going to the cops !

Comment: should i use vpn while using facebook to hide my ip??

Comment: You can do so, but AFAIK there isn't a way to determine the IP address of a user on Facebook other than to ask Facebook itself via legal request, or by the other means stated by Bill. Also, please change your Facebook account password to a strong one: after all, if he manages to gain access to your FB account because you use a weak password, he would be able to determine the IP address you used to login to FB, which if you are not using a VPN is your real IP.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments have noted, you can't trust a compromised machine to honestly report about itself. You could extract the hard drive for analysis on another machine, but that would involve lots of time and effort.

Faster and easier to just remove the attacker.

- Reset your router to factory defaults - almost all will have a little button on the back that you can push and hold to do so. This will probably remove any config changes the attacker has made. Reconfigure the router using settings obtained from your ISP.
- Rebuild your laptop from known good media. Download Ubuntu again and re-install it.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to know who is behind this. Ask the person directly and threaten that you're going to the cops about it ?? This is definitely illegal and you could have a go at that route.

But there is no escaping the fact that a reinstall is due & a router reset.

Comment: he wont be bothered if i threaten him coz the cops out here know nothing abt cyberattacks and willn't give a ear over the matter